# Regex to ensure HTTPS URL schema

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace `'http://'` with `'https://'` in a URL (if the former exists); and if `'http://'` or `'https://'` is not the prefix (schema), then I need to prefix the URL with `'https://'`.

I can simply check if the URL begins with `'http'` and prefix it to `'https'` accordingly or replace `'http'` if it exists.  It's that simple and takes 2 lines of code, BUT...

Is it possible to do it with one line with a JavaScript regex function?

Comment: If you know how to do it, why would it be important to do in one line. Are you looking for [**Code Golf Stack Exchange**](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: use the ternary operator. posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function simpleHttpsPrefixer(url) {
    return url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*)/, "https://$1");
}
```

Comment: As it stands, this prepends `'https://'` to a URL that already begins with `'https://'`, yielding `'https://https://'`.

Comment: @J0e3gan: you're right - only ran two test cases when writing the function. Fixed, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
var str = "http://www.whatever.com.au";
str = str.replace("http://", "https://");
alert(str);
```

If you want to one-line it:

```
url = url.replace("http://", "https://");
```

Comment: @dr_dev, thanks for pointing that out. I forgot to reassign the str variable to the new string. But yes, it does work :P

Answer (score 0):

### Regex Solution

Yes, it is possible to do this in one statement using a JS regex replace:

```
url = url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*)/, "https://$1");
```

The snippet below demonstrates the above single-statement, regex solution with `http`, `https`, and schemaless URLs.

```js
var schemalessUrl = "www.whatever.com.au";
var httpUrl = "http://www.whatever.com.au";
var httpsUrl = "https://www.whatever.com.au";

var urls = [schemalessUrl, httpUrl, httpsUrl];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    urls[i] = urls[i].replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*)/, 'https://$1');
    console.log(urls[i]);
    alert(urls[i]);
}
```

### Non-regex Solution

It is also possible to do this in a single statement without a regex replace of course.  The ternary conditional operator can collapse just about anything into one statement (for better and worse):

```
url = url.indexOf('http://') === 0 ? url.replace('http://', 'https://') : (url.indexOf('https://') !== 0 ? 'https://' + url : url);
```

The snippet below similarly demonstrates the above single-statement, *non-*regex solution with `http`, `https`, and schemaless URLs.

```js
var schemalessUrl = "www.whatever.com.au";
var httpUrl = "http://www.whatever.com.au";
var httpsUrl = "https://www.whatever.com.au";

var urls = [schemalessUrl, httpUrl, httpsUrl];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    urls[i] = urls[i].indexOf('http://') === 0 ? urls[i].replace('http://', 'https://') : (urls[i].indexOf('https://') !== 0 ? 'https://' + urls[i] : urls[i]);
    console.log(urls[i]);
    alert(urls[i]);
}
```

Having said this, I prefer the regex solution, but TMTOWTDI.